# Why doesn't the message appear with I use smtp.sendmail(toAddress, fromAddress, message)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I made an app for a practice project in [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/) that takes a list of chores and assigns a random chore to each email address in a list of emails. The emails I'm using are for outlook and gmail, they are my own accounts. The basic code for sending the message looks like this:

```py
smtpObj = smtp.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login(<my_email>, password>
smtp.sendmail(my_email, <email_from_list>, message)
```

It sends the emails just fine but they are empty when they are received. Why is this?

Comment: Is the last line not meant to be `smtpObj.sendmail(my_email, email_from_list, message)`?

Comment: Please add `print(f'"{message}"')` just before the last line, and then post the result.

Comment: It prints out the string prepared for the message variable.

Comment: Can you view the raw email in your mailbox and see if the message is there (but hidden).

Comment: There is no message at all.

Comment: To confirm, there is a message in your inbox (*"but they are empty when they are received"*), from you to you, but there is no content? You should be able to view the raw text that has all the information that that the SMTP server received.

Comment: There's an email in the inbox with no subject or message within the email.